# Get transition percentage in UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, transition, presentviewcontroller

I've two UIViews presented in the same UINavigationController; View A & View B.

During the transition, because I want to apply some custom animation styles, I want to know the percentage of the progress of the presentation inside the UINavigationController. How do I do this?

I want a function like this:

```
class ExampleNavigationController: UINavigationController {


    func viewControllerMoves(from: UIViewController, to: UIViewController, progress: CGFloat) {
        //I can read here how far the animation is and apply custom animation styles

    }

}
```

This function should also be called during an update by the user:
Example --> http://www.latet.nl/appvideo.mov

How do I do this?

**Example screens**

Percentage would be 0.50

[image: 50/50]

Percentage would be 1.00

[image: 100%]

Percentage would be 0.00

[image: 0%]

Answer (score 0):

The `UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator` protocol provides exactly what you need. In `UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext`, you will find a `percentComplete` that works for interactive transitions. For non-interactive transitions, it has all you need to animate alongside them.